# Using a group of cells like a function

Tags: function, google-sheets

I setup a group of cells like a function in coding, with a number of cells being input variables which do some calculations and finally spit the result into another cell.

I would like to populate another group of cells in a table using this "cell function"

Here is what I envision it would be like, with the function taking in (Cell to apply value, value, and result) for the "do" function.

[image]

How would I do this in google sheets?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to accomplish. Can you provide a sample spreadsheet indicating the desired workflow?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(violet_cell, {yellow_cell, blue_cell}, 2, 0))
```

Comment: This only works if the desired value is kept in the var cell, the desired operation would be able to use the varcell and resultcell combo to populate many cells without requiring many varcell/resultcell combinations. Only one "Cell Formula" to do so.